# How can I retrieve the item that the user selected from the drop down? in jsf

Tags: jsf

My question is how can i **retrieve  selected item in backing bean** ?

In my view page i have one select box component :

`<h:selectOneMenu id="materialCat"
                            value="#

  {materialMasterBean.materialDTOs.materialCategoryId}" required="true"    requiredMessage="Material Category is Mandatory">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="select" itemValue="-1" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{materialMasterBean.materialCatList}" />

                        </h:selectOneMenu>`

This is my backing bean

`  public ArrayList getMaterialCatList() {
        if(materialCatList == null )
        {

```
        materialCatList= new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        ArrayList<MaterialDTO> temp;
        try {
                temp= getAdminDelegate().getMaterialLsit();
                for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++)
                    {
                    MaterialDTO materialDTO = temp.get(i);
                        item = new SelectItem(materialDTO.getMaterialCategoryId(),materialDTO.getMaterialCategory());
                        materialCatList.add(item);
                    }
            } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

        return materialCatList;
    }
    else
    {
        return materialCatList;
    }

}
```

`
also in backing Bean i have:

`private MaterialDTO materialDTOs;`

please help me

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can't you just access `materialDTOs.getMaterialCategoryId()` in action method? JSF has already set it there.

Comment: Why is that a problem? What exactly happens instead? You are really not clear in describing the concrete problem.

Comment: Uh, just in action method which you've bound to a command link or button? Have you ever been through chapter 1 of a bit decent JSF book/tutorial? It's not different from other input fields or something.

Comment: Just edit this question and explain clearly. Please try writing formal English. Not everyone understands street/childish talk like "u", "ur" and so on.

Comment: sorry for that , and i got my answer. thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

you can access it in your bean if you binded it with the `value="#{bean.filed}` attribute

EDIT: [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-dropdown-box-example/) is an example on how to do a selectonebox, i think you missunderstood some things. Do you want to select a `MaterialDTO` Object in the list? or an Id? You dont need an ArrayList with `SelectItem` ...

Comment: i tried that but it gives error as  javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /pages/MaterialMasterl.xhtml @45,73 binding="materialMasterBean.materialCode": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation